# Elasticsearch: How to use wildcards in percolator query

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I am creating some percolator queries that look like the one below:

```
{
    "search_term": "*a1c*",
    "highlight": {
        "fields": [
            "assessment",
            "complaint",
            "exam",
            "history"
         ],
        "post_tags": [
            "~~"
        ],
        "pre_tags": [
            "~~"
        ]
    },
    "query": {
        "multi_match": {
            "fields": [
                "assessment",
                "complaint",
                "exam",
                "history",
            ],
            "query": "*a1c*",
            "type": "phrase"
        }
    }
}
```

What I want is to search a document like

```
"patient's hemoglobin a1c is ..."
```

and return the result

```
"patient's hemoglobin ~~a1c~~ is..."
```

This is currently working with the query above. However, I want it to also be able to locate the term 'a1c' when it's a substring, like in

```
"patient's hba1c is..."
```

or

```
 "patientsa1cmeasurementis..."
```

However, elasticsearch only matches 'a1c' as a standalone string, and won't identify substrings despite having the wildcards in the search terms. What am I doing wrong here? If it helps, I don't care about execution time (I know the wildcards are slow) and it would be great to keep the highlighting, but if the two are mutually exclusive then I am okay to get rid of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your multi_search to

```
"query":{
  "query_string":{
     "query":"*a1c*",
     "fields":[
        "assessment",
        "complaint",
        "exam"
     ]
  }}
```

With this query '`patient's hba1c is...`' will be '`patient's ~~hba1c~~ is...`'
and 
"`patientsa1cmeasurementis...`" will be `"~patientsa1cmeasurementis...~~"`